# String creation of file pathin char format with Qt (VC++)

Tags: qt, path, formatting

I want to create a GUI application using Qt. For that I need to get the filename using:

```
QString fileName=getOpenFileName(.....)
```

I am using Windows and want to have the filename path in C:\a\b\c format and pass it to a function accepting char variables. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Qt FAQ](http://qt-project.org/faq/answer/how_can_i_convert_a_qstring_to_char_and_vice_versa)

```
QString path = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(...);
QByteArray byteArray = path.toLocal8Bit();
const char *charPath = byteArray.data();
```

Comment: Might want to do a QDir::toNativeSeparators( path ), too, to ensure "\" on Windows.